# Rid of {one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?} string in Laravel 5 routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, controller, routes

I am looking for an option how can I remove {one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?} this from routes.
This is automatically added in every routes
like

```
v1/webapi/login/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}
v1/webapi/logout/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}
```

In routes file m using below route

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'middleware' => 'webapi'], function(){
    Route::controller('webapi', 'WebApiController');
});
```

Can anyone have the same problem?

Comment: Can you show the code from `webapi`?

Comment: webapi is controller file where I have all the functions written

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is - You can't remove it. This method https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerInspector.php#L132 add those wildcard parameters.

The only way to get rid of it is to rewrite `Router` and use your own `ControllerInspector`, but this is pointless and pretty hard to achieve.

---

**UPDATE**

But if You really want to do it, there is one hacky solution:

```
    foreach (\Route::getRoutes() as $route) {
        $route->setUri(preg_replace('%\{one\?\}/\{two\?\}/\{three\?\}/\{four\?\}/\{five\?\}$%', '',
            $route->getUri()));
    }
```

put this code in `RouteServiceProvider.php` `boot` method.